Problem sending Ublox message `RXM-PMREQ` using Raspberry-pi-pico
Im trying to configure a GPS to be in power save mode, cyclic tracking mode. Then i want to manually place him in inactive mode for 5 minutes using the Ublox message RXM-PMREQ. The command is not working, and it seems to not even be recognized since i dont receive a ACK message back
The message I am having trouble implementing is:
Message structure
Message information given
These are all the relevant functions defined in C using Pico's SDK:
// Get the current time in milliseconds
uint32_t get_millis() {
    return to_ms_since_boot(get_absolute_time());
}

//===================================================UBlox functions====================================================//

// Function to print UBlox message in hexadecimal format
void print_ublox_message(const uint8_t* message, size_t length) {
    printf("UBlox Message Sent: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%02X ", message[i]);  // Print each byte as a two-digit hexadecimal value
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// Function to calculate the UBX checksum
void add_ublox_checksum(uint8_t* message, size_t length, uint8_t* ck_a, uint8_t* ck_b) {
    *ck_a = 0;
    *ck_b = 0;
    //calculate
    for (size_t i = 2; i < length - 2; i++) {  // Skip the sync chars and exclude checksum bytes
        *ck_a += message[i];
        *ck_b += *ck_a;
    }
    if (debug) printf("checksum finished, CK_A: %02X, CK_B: %02X\n", *ck_a, *ck_b);
    //append
    message[length - 2] = *ck_a;
    message[length - 1] = *ck_b;
}

// Function to calculate and check the UBX checksum
bool verify_ublox_checksum(uint8_t* message, size_t length) {
    if (length < 4) {  // Minimum length: 2 sync chars + 2 checksum bytes
        printf("Message too short to have a valid checksum.\n");
        return false;
    }

    uint8_t ck_a = 0, ck_b = 0;
    // Calculate checksum (skip the sync chars and exclude checksum bytes)
    for (size_t i = 2; i < length - 2; i++) {
        ck_a += message[i];
        ck_b += ck_a;
    }

    // Compare calculated checksum with the appended checksum
    if (ck_a == message[length - 2] && ck_b == message[length - 1]) {
        return 1;  // Checksum is valid
    } else {
        printf("Invalid checksum! Calculated CK_A: %02X, CK_B: %02X, but received CK_A: %02X, CK_B: %02X\n",
               ck_a, ck_b, message[length - 2], message[length - 1]);
        return 0;  // Checksum is invalid
    }
}

int wait_for_ublox_ack(uint8_t* response_buffer) {
    uint32_t start_time = get_millis();
    size_t bytes_received = 0;
    uint8_t current_byte;

    while (get_millis() - start_time < ACK_TIMEOUT_MS) {
        // Check if data is available in the UART RX FIFO
        while (uart_is_readable(UART_ID)) {
            current_byte = uart_getc(UART_ID);
            if (debug) printf("current_byte: 0x%02X\n", current_byte);  // Print byte in hexadecimal format

            if (bytes_received < ACK_UBOX_SIZE) {
                if (current_byte == 0xB5 && bytes_received == 0) { //1st byte of ACK Header
                    response_buffer[bytes_received++] = current_byte;
                }
                else if (current_byte == 0x62 && bytes_received == 1) { //2nd byte of ACK Header
                    response_buffer[bytes_received++] = current_byte;
                }
                else if (current_byte == 0x05 && bytes_received == 2) { //1st byte of ACK ID
                    response_buffer[bytes_received++] = current_byte;
                }
                else if ((current_byte == 0x01 || current_byte == 0x00) && bytes_received == 3) { //2nd byte of ACK ID(1 for acknowledge and 0 for not acknowledge)
                    response_buffer[bytes_received++] = current_byte;
                }
                else if (bytes_received > 3) {
                    response_buffer[bytes_received++] = current_byte;
                    if (bytes_received == ACK_UBOX_SIZE) {
                        printf("ACK UBlox Message Received: ");
                        for (size_t i = 0; i < ACK_UBOX_SIZE; i++) {
                            printf("%02X ", response_buffer[i]);
                        }
                        printf("\n");

                        // Verify the checksum of the received message
                        if (verify_ublox_checksum(response_buffer, ACK_UBOX_SIZE)) {
                            return 1; // Success
                        } else {
                            return 0; // Failure
                        }
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    // If the sequence is broken, reset and start looking for a new start of the message
                    bytes_received = 0;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    // Timeout occurred
    printf("Timeout: No UBlox response received within %d ms, ", ACK_TIMEOUT_MS);
    printf("Received Buffer: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ACK_UBOX_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%02X ", response_buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;  // Failure
}


// Send the UBlox configuration message to the GPS module
void send_ublox_message(uint8_t* message, size_t length, int ack_needed) { 
    uint8_t ck_a, ck_b;
    //generate and append ublox checksum
    add_ublox_checksum(message, length, &ck_a, &ck_b);
    // Print the message in hexadecimal format
    print_ublox_message(message, length);
    // UART write function
    uart_write_blocking(UART_ID, message, length);
    if (ack_needed == 1){
        // Buffer to wait response
        uint8_t uart_rx_buffer[ACK_UBOX_SIZE]; 
        //Wait for response
        wait_for_ublox_ack(uart_rx_buffer);
    }
    else{
        sleep_ms(1000);
    }
}

void initial_ublox_configuration(){
    //Enable Power Save Mode using CFG-RXM
    uint8_t cfg_message[] = {
        0xB5, 0x62,              // Sync chars for UBX protocol
        0x06, 0x11,              // CFG-RXM message class (0x06) and ID (0x11)
        0x02, 0x00,              // Length (2 bytes)
        0x08,                    // reserved1: always be set to 8
        0x01,                    // lpMode:  1 = PSM
        0x00, 0x00               // Placeholder for checksum(appended later)
    };
    // Configure the Power Management using CFG-PM2
    uint8_t pm2_message[] = {
        0xB5, 0x62,              // Sync chars for UBX protocol
        0x06, 0x3B,              // CFG-PM2 message class (0x06) and ID (0x3B)
        0x2C, 0x00,              // Length in bytes (44 bytes = 0x2C)
        0x01,                    // Version (should be set to 1)
        0x00,                    // reserved1
        0x00,                    // reserved2
        0x00,                    // reserved3
        0x00, 0xA0, 0x58, 0x00,  // Flags bits 0->31 described in README
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Position Update period in ms (0 ms)
        0x10, 0x27, 0x00, 0x00,  // Search period in ms (10seconds, 10000ms = 0x2710)
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Grid offset in ms (0ms)
        0x05, 0x00,              // On-time in s (5 seconds = 0x05)
        0x05, 0x00,              // Minimum acquisition time in s (5 seconds = 0x05)
        0x00, 0x00,              // reserved4
        0x00, 0x00,              // reserved5
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // reserved6
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // reserved7   
        0x00,                    // reserved8
        0x00,                    // reserved9
        0x00, 0x00,              // reserved10
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // reserved11
        0x00, 0x00               // Placeholder for checksum
    };

    // Send the cfg_message and pm2_message
    send_ublox_message(cfg_message, sizeof(cfg_message), 1);
    send_ublox_message(pm2_message, sizeof(pm2_message), 1);
}

But the most important is:
void force_inactive(){
    //Force the receiver to enter Inactive mode using RXM-PMREQ
    uint8_t rxm_message[] = {
        0xB5, 0x62,              // Sync chars for UBX protocol
        0x02, 0x41,              // RXM-PMREQ message class (0x02) and ID (0x41)
        0x08, 0x00,              // Length (8 bytes)
        0xE0, 0x93, 0x04, 0x00,  // Duration of the inactive time in ms (5minutes, 300000ms = 0x0493E0)
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Task flags (01000000=0x40 The receiver goes into backup mode; 00000000=x000 doesnt go into backup mode)
        0x00, 0x00               // Placeholder for checksum(appended later)
    };

    //send the rxm_message
    send_ublox_message(rxm_message, sizeof(rxm_message), 1);
}

Then in my main function i do after initializing UART:
//Enable and Configure Power Save 
initial_ublox_configuration();
force_inactive();

and i get the output:
UBlox Message Sent: B5 62 06 11 02 00 08 01 22 92 
ACK UBlox Message Received: B5 62 05 01 02 00 06 11 1F 48 
UBlox Message Sent: B5 62 06 3B 2C 00 01 00 00 00 00 A0 58 00 00 00 00 00 10 27 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A7 18 
ACK UBlox Message Received: B5 62 05 01 02 00 06 3B 49 72 
UBlox Message Sent: B5 62 02 41 08 00 E0 93 04 00 00 00 00 00 C2 50 
Timeout: No UBlox response received within 20000 ms, Received Buffer: 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 05 00

I thought maybe the message is not compatible but on startup this message is received
Txt Message: $GPTXT,01,01,02,u-blox ag - www.u-blox.com*50
Txt Message: $GPTXT,01,01,02,HW  UBX-G60xx  00040007 FF7FFFFFp*53
Txt Message: $GPTXT,01,01,02,ROM CORE 7.03 (45969) Mar 17 2011 16:18:34*59
Txt Message: $GPTXT,01,01,02,ANTSUPERV=AC SD PDoS SR*20
Txt Message: $GPTXT,01,01,02,ANTSTATUS=DONTKNOW*33
Txt Message: $GPTXT,01,01,02,ANTSTATUS=INIT*25
Txt Message: $GPTXT,01,01,02,ANTSTATUS=OK*3B

So by the datasheet ROM CORE 7.03 (45969) Mar 17 2011 16:18:34*59 uses ublox 6 so the message should be compatible. Any one has any idea what is going on??
